# How do I link specific Flask form data to a Bootstrap button

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to make three button options that fill a Flask form with specific data that is already hard coded (example: yellow button = 1, red button = 2, blue button = 3, and so on), but I'm not really sure how to.

This is some of my code:

**forms.py**

```
class NewClientForm(FlaskForm):
    name= StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    category = StringField('Category')  # <-- THE ONE I WANT TO CHANGE TO BUTTONS
    notes = TextAreaField('Notes')
    submit = SubmitField('Create')
```

**form.html**

```html
<div class = "form-group">
    {{ form.category.label(class = "form-control-label") }}
    {% if form.category.errors %}
        {{ form.category(class = "form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
        <div class = "invalid-feedback">
            {% for error in form.category.errors %}
                <span>{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {{ form.category(class = "form-control form-control-lg") }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**routes.py**

```
@app.route("/new_client", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def new_client():
    form = NewClientForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        client = Client(name=form.name.data, category=form.category.data, notes=form.notes.data)
        db.session.add(client)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Now I can only submit written data instead of hardcoded data.

This is how it looks:

[image]